# I realized I am too stupid to buy individual stocks, should I use "robo-advisor" consulting?

Tags: index-fund, capital-loss, switzerland, robo-advisor

First the facts:

I opened a Swissquote account in mid 2018 (a broker similar to Robinhood in the US).

My balance today: loss of -1'500 CHF, with a total investment of 26'000 francs.

*Especially the Coinbase and Gitlab shares have contributed to the loss. I was massively wrong.*

Some others perform well, from some Swiss companies I even get dividends.

Actually I like to buy stocks, is like a little hobby, but my results are very bad. Especially compared to the market average.

I realized I am too stupid to buy individual stocks, should I use a robo-advisor?

Another option would be to just buy index funds, that is also advised a lot here and from my friends.

Comment: You either trade or you hold single shares so long you make profit. Getting nervous at the first low is bad. Dividends are paid according to available cash; not according to the share price.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Actually I like to buy stocks, is like a little hobby, but my results
> are very bad. Especially compared to the market average.

So buy the index funds that mirror the market average. Very little research is needed and there is no need to check daily, weekly, or monthly to determine if you need to switch investments.

If you do decide you want to move away from those market defining index funds, there are other funds that will invest in either a region of the world, or a sector.  The return in those specialized funds will either help of hurt your performance, but at least you don't have to constantly search for individual stocks.

You have to decide how much your hobby will cost you in time, and money. If the money in the market is supposed to a source of current or future living expenses, you don't want your hobby to impact your quality of life.

Comment: "you don't want your hobby to impact your quality of life" - Nicely put. If someone's hobby is going to Disneyland Paris every year, they might set aside 1'000 CHF each year for their hobby. You can do the same for your stock-picking hobby.